# Strange behavior in ggplot summary groupings

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am getting unreasonable numbers in my bar plot (`geom_col`, for sums) when grouping values. The plot below shows a summed weight (`wt`) of around 2.5 for cars with 4 cylinders and 3 gears, and a summed weight
of around 3.5 for cars with 6 cylinders and three gears. The former is reasonable, as the `summarised` weight is 2.46, but the latter makes no sense, as the `summarised` weight is 6.68. It's more pronounced for 3 cylinders and 8 gears (plot shows around 5.5, `summarised` weight is 49.2)

```
mtcars_ex = 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl),
         gear = as.character(gear))

ggplot(data = mtcars_ex,
       aes(y = wt,
           x = gear,
           fill = cyl)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge",
           na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
mtcars_ex %>% group_by(cyl,gear) %>% summarise(sum(wt))
#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#  cyl   gear  `sum(wt)`
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#1 4     3          2.46
#2 4     4         19.0 
#3 4     5          3.65
#4 6     3          6.68
#5 6     4         12.4 
#6 6     5          2.77
#7 8     3         49.2 
#8 8     5          6.74
```

Comment: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,gear) %>% summarise(max(wt))` is what you are seeing, you are plotting all the values as bars and seeing only the max value, add `alpha = 0.1` to `geom_col` to verify

Comment: How can I get sums?

Comment: pre-calculate before the graph or call `stat_summary` with `fun = "max"` and `geom = "col"`

Comment: Man... so simple. Thanks! Add as answer?

Comment: @akrun I trust the behavior has not changed - `geom_col`  plots all the values as bars, if the values overlap, they fill be plotted one in front of the others - therefore its best to aggregate the data  either prior calling `geom_col` or within `stat_summary`.

Comment: Yeah, this approach with the pre-aggregation worked well with geom_col.